# How to convert html string code into an actual html working code that will appear in front end?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, templates

I am using a v-for"item in items"
then I have values in my {{ item.data }} which is an html element but with a values already, example

{{ item.data }} has a value of a string "<'qr-code value="this has specific infos that is already created for this specific code" '>"

so when I would run it on my page with just {{ item.data }} , this will show up

<'qr-code value="this has specific infos that is already created for this specific code" '>

it prints the html code and not running it.

BUT when i try to copy that code and paste it in my html, it works.
it is just how can I make this string code into an actual working HTML code
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive v-html will render content from string as plain HTML, you can use like this example.

```
<div v-html=“yourVar”></div>
```

If you need more information, here more examples:

https://nexladder.com/vuejs-tutorial/vuejs-v-html-directive

Comment: I have tried that BUT there would be a problem. If I would place it in my data -> content: then the value would fixed and not dynamic as how I wanted it to be.

Comment: because im using {{ items.data }} from a for loop, if I put a v-html on a tag, all of my iteration would have the same value because of the fixed content.

Comment: Try to use this.$forceUpdate() right after your loop ends

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the situation correctly you are looking for the component tag.

You can use :is="" to set the element node type.

You can find more information here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components